# Does it look bad on my CV if I leave my second Android developer job after 6 months due to interpersonal difficulties with a co-worker?

Tags: professionalism, resume, job-change, unprofessional-behavior

I am 3 months into by second android developer job. I was with my previous company for 2½ years and have been with my current company for 3 months (out of a 6 month contract).

I have my mid-term evaluation tomorrow and feel this is an appropriate time to bring up my difficulties with a co-worker. I don't feel I can continue to work in this environment without becoming dissatisfied with my job and ultimately dreading going to work every day. This difficulty is simply due to incompatible personalities so it's not something I can report to HR or which can necessarily be remedied in any way (besides me leaving).

I would be more than happy to seek a new position as I am not attached to my job or where I live, however I do not have any kind of a university degree so my work experience is all I have, and I can't imagine a scenario where this would not be a huge black mark on my CV and compromise my ability to get another position.

Is this a reasonable assessment? Is it necessary that I should remain with my current company for a minimum of 2 years so as to to give future employers the impression that I am reliable and will remain with them for a substantial amount of time. I feel my reason for leaving will also sound suspect as future employers may think I am not a team player and not worth hiring.

Comment: You say you are a contractor on a 6 month contract why are you concerned to stay for 2 years as a contractor? Contractors move around  a lot more that full time employees

Comment: I'm not a contractor, I have a 6 month contract which will be renewed for an 18 month contract and then a permanent contract if I was to stay with the company and if they want to keep me.

Comment: That depends on what's actually going on there. This smells of an episode of bulling. Typically the bully chooses a victim who is reluctant to talk about the problem with others.

Comment: It's not bullying, I just don't want to work this person because I find them _extremely_ irritating.

Comment: In that case my advice is try to find new job while working there, so the reason to leave will be you found something better. Getting a better job never looks bad on your CV.

Comment: The simple answer is "no" - software is so fast paced nobody cares if you left after six months.  Obviously it is **inconceivable** you would mention you don't get along with people.  In your CV you don't give any reason, whatsoever, why you left somewhere.  You just state where you worked and what you did.

Comment: "future employers may think I am not a team player and not worth hiring'  From what you have said you **are not** a team player.  Every single human being who has ever worked anywhere, has suffered "incompatible personalities" with a colleague.  Every. Single. Person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned that you have a definite 6-month contract with your current employer...
Then you have nothing to worry about, and if you are called for an interview with another company, you can state that your current employment is on a definite contract (that of six months), and they have not given any indication whether they will renew the contract or not, thus you are looking for opportunities with other companies, especially if the contract's end date would be nearing. However, be careful how to put this, as some might misinterpret this and suspect that you are not good at your job, thus your current employer has a valid reason not to renew your employment contract. If definite contracts are not the norm in your area or you are willing to migrate to other countries, in which definite employment contracts are not the norm, then you can state that you are not comfortable with job contracts on definite-basis and prefer indefinite basis contracts, because definite-basis contracts offer uncertainties which you are not comfortable with.

You should read some online articles regarding the subject (example: https://www.thebalance.com/interview-questions-about-why-you-want-to-change-jobs-2061154), reflect on the given reasons, evaluate which reasons suit best your current situation and use them during an interview. If you choose a reason/s related to your skills, experience etc., make sure that it also reflects on your CV.

You also mentioned that you do not have enough qualifications (a university degree). You should consider in getting qualifications, as these would make your profile look more attractive towards prospective employers, and you will be offered better packages (such as salary).

Do other colleagues share the same opinion or show signs/indications (that they are not comfortable with this colleague) about this colleague of yours, with whom you have clashes with? If yes, then you should consider mentioning this with the HR, however without any negative remarks. It could be that other colleagues have also brought this to the HR's attention, and they would look for a solution, and you would not have to leave the company simply because you are not comfortable with a colleague with whom others also have problems with. However, be careful with this approach, especially if this colleague has joined the company before you, as this could make you look the "villain" of the situation, and that you are trying to put him in difficult situations, with the intention of taking his place, if HR interprets your comments in a wrong way.

Comment: I work in the Netherlands where by law you must give an employee 2 temporary contracts followed by a permanent one. Now that you mention it that makes a lot of sense, why would I not begin looking for another role when there is no assertion that I will have a job in another 3 months? Trying to get a qualification would be highly disruptive to my life and I am happy with the money I make. Other colleagues do not share this opinion, the co-worker I have an issue with talks down to me because I'm new, and wastes my time "teaching me" despite his being a lesser programmer who I frequently correct.

Comment: If he is trying to put you down and insinuate that he is wasting his time in training you, when in fact you frequently correct his mistakes ( as you are stating), then he is either afraid that eventually you will be seen more efficient and a better employee than he is and you will eventually take his place or he is jealous of your skills.

Comment: I don't necessarily feel it's so sinister, I just think he's naive, but regardless of the reasons or motivations the case is that my work environment is becoming increasingly unpleasant for me and I have no attachment to this job or this country, so I do not feel as though I am being chased out of the company, I simply feel that there is probably a better environment out there for me and I would rather move and get more experience in other parts of the world rather than try to force my situation here to work.

Comment: If your superiors think highly of you and your work, then you should let your superiors know of this situation, however without stating that you are considering the option to leave the company. If they value you, then they will do their utmost to solve this problem. If they do not share their opinion on your work, then let them know of the situation without giving any particular details.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned if people are incompatible they are incompatible and trying to force people to act in a certain way only leads to tension and ultimately the problem builds up and comes out much worse than it would have otherwise. I no longer think it is worth my while to bring this issue up with my manager as there is no action I want them to take. I wanted to bring it up as a heads up that I may leave which I now realise I shouldnt do. I will begin the process of searching for a new position so I have the option to leave if my relationship with my co worker doesn't improve in 3 months

Comment: Keep in mind that such people are found everywhere, and one should not let obstacles get in their way. Imagine this situation in a different scenario, whereby you do not wish to leave the company simply because of this "colleague". What do you do? Let the obstacle get in your way, or do your utmost to overcome this challenge? This colleague is the problem and not you.
I advise you to try solving this problem in your current workplace (Plan A), and start to look for other job opportunities, just in case things do not develop the way you want them to (Plan B).

Comment: That last comment really says it all. Learn how to deal with obstacles, because one day you might be in a situation where you can't circumvent such a person, and may end up abandoning a dream job.

Answer (score 7):

Well, **yes**, it looks pretty bad *if* your stated reason for leaving is "can't get get along with coworker".

However, you're the one in control of your job search, so you can spin it more positively. The IT industry is pretty mobile and 6 months is not going to ring too many alarm bells, particularly if your previous engagement was longer and if you weren't fired.  Perhaps you're leaving because (say) the job didn't offer you the opportunity for growth that you expected, and that's why New Job looks much better?

In any case, the key is that you grit your teeth for a bit longer, find a new job while still working there, and only then quit.  Otherwise explaining why you left will be more difficult.

As an aside, your situation sounds rather odd to me, you might want to bring this up with your manager and/or explore other roles in the company if this co-worker of yours is the only problem.

Comment: How much of this do you think I should share with my manager during my mid-term evaluation tomorrow? Should I be completely honest and explain that I am going to start looking for a new position starting immediately, so in another 3 months when my contract is up for renewal I will have the freedom to decide to remain with my current company or leave? Should I bring up anything at all?

Comment: @Moses In my experience if you tell an employer you want to leave them, it's quite likely that they would fire you. They are investing in you and since you want to leave them, you represent a waste money for every second you remain in the company.

Comment: @derloopkat well, that's not really true. I mean, how much effort do companies actually spend on training? It's pretty mediocre. Also, OP is a contract worker, so they're not *investing* in the OP at all. To the OP - you should bring this up with your manager, but not that you're looking to leave. It's perfectly fine to bring up interpersonal issues, as long as you do it politely - "Danny smells and I wake up earlier each day just to hate Danny longer" is vastly different from "Danny and I have different work styles, and I'm finding i'm not as effective when I work with Danny"

Comment: @bharal, No, he's not a contract worker. OP is on probation which is carried out on a contract basis. If he's successful, the company is intending to give him a permanent job. Second, OP is Android Developer. How much an IT company spend? A lot. As software devs we have to learn everything they have done to be able to maintain it. If we're given a new project then company needs to pass knowledge about this when we leave.